# mixing clientside javascript template with rails logic for backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I've worked a while now with Backbone.js, and one of the things I nowadays run into is; Sometimes you need to have serverside logic into a .eco.jst template

For example

- an i18n translation (currently look at i18n.js gem for this)
- a path a route without hardcoding it (somemodel_path(somemodel))
- authorisation (for example, show a delete button if the user can destroy this model). Atm I solve this by passing in some rights object in the json that gets filled in.
- Rendering a html helper like simple_form or S3_file_uploader (atm I solve this with rendering it serverside, and put the display on none)

As you know, .eco get parsed by node.js, so I can't call ruby in the eco files. Most of these problems I solve by basicly creating a "data" object in the head. Similar to this:

```
window.data = {
    some_translation = "<%= t('cool') %>",
    <%= "can_destoy_model = true," if can?('destroy', Model) %>
    post_edit_link = "<%= post_path(@post) %>
}
```

Besides this being bulky (this is just an example, normally this would be more ordened or I add a html5 data attribute to some dom element), It's time consuming, sometimes you have to recreate complete business logic which otherwise would be a oneliner in rails (take for example the S3_file_uploader, which requires encoded amazon policyfile and a token)

What are your thoughts about this? Should I perhaps not use .eco (although I like templates in seperate files instead of poluting the view). Would I able to use serverside logic if I for instance used mustache or handlebars and which gem would you recommend if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with Backbone.js is kind of limited, but I've managed to setup an environment with logic-less templates using the following gems:

- [handlebars_assets](https://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets)
- [haml_assets](https://github.com/carezone/haml_assets)

And a bunch of other stuff, even a mini-framework I'm currently working on (you can find it [here](https://github.com/sergelerator/sharkbone))

I picked this approach for building [Single Page Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) using Backbone.

Basically, the `haml_assets` gem provides [sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) with the ability to parse `.haml` files, this is not needed but I love HAML syntax. The `handlebars_assets` gem provides means to parse Handlebars templates, both on the server-side and the client-side. You can use Ruby code inside the templates and you would solve both the i18n and the path methods problems you mentioned.

I've found these tools to be excellent to help DRY an application's templates, and it can really save you from adding logic inside templates. If you use Backbone Views to take, for example, decisions on whether to show a `delete` button or not, you can keep the logic inside the Backbone View, and use that logic to render the proper Handlebars template (or partial).

Using your example:

Coffeescript:

```
class ProjectShowView extends Backbone.View
  template: (context) -> HandlebarsTemplates['projects/show'](context)
  deleteButtonTemplate: (context) -> HandlebarsTemplates['projects/shared/delete_button'](context)

  render: (canDelete = false) ->
    @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON()))
    @$('.delete_button_container').append(@deleteButtonTemplate()) if canDelete
    @
```

The example is quite primitive and basic, but can hopefully point in the right direction. I hope it helps!

Comment: How would you define canDelete if you put it in the View? Wouldnt it be better to put it in the handlerbars template (perhaps with partials if this is possible?). Else I still have to dump random json objects in the dom to handle rights.

Comment: This is just an example of things you could do, you can make models for about anything you want i.e. a Session model, that stores a Permission model inside with all the permissions related data. This way you might be able to do something like `@$('.delete_button_container').append(@deleteButtonTemplate()) if App.Session.can_delete("project")`
How you structure the application to fill the permissions data (for example filling it upon page load) is up to you. This approach though, requires that you handle many stuff on the client side... Otherwise, I find it hard to get rid of logic in templates